# Returning an empty JSON object when a nullable column value is null within an eloquent query scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have the following query scope that will return keys (JSON) that may be stored inside a container:

```
public function scopeKeys($query, $container)
{
    return $query->select('keys')
        ->whereNotNull('keys')
        ->where('name', $container)
        ->value('keys');
}
```

...in my controller I access this via:

```
Containers::keys($container);
```

When the keys exists, I get them back as expected; however; when the `keys` field is null, I get the following error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

I'd like to avoid using `firstOrFail()` as I don't want to throw a 404, I want to return an empty JSON object.

I'm sure I could utilize `->exists()` to check then conditionally return but then I'm making two queries if they do exist - seems sloppy.

Comment: What about `firstOrFail` and try/catch? And return empty JSON in catch block.

Comment: also check firstOr() ?

Comment: Looks like problem not in scope query. `value` method can return only `null` or passed column value. Please, show full code and exception trace.

Comment: I've checked your query in Tinker and it returns `null` when there isn't any match, it doesn't throw any error. How are you handling the response of this method in your controller?

Comment: public function index($container)
    {
        $rsp = Containers::keys($container);

        return response($rsp)
            ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'text/json']);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Scopes aren't meant to execute queries, only to prepare them.

You can execute the query outside the scope:

```
public function scopeKeys($query, $container)
{
    return $query->select('keys')
        ->whereNotNull('keys')
        ->where('name', $container);
}

$keys = Containers::keys($container)->value('keys');
```

Or you define a "normal" static method:

```
public static function keys($container)
{
    return static::query()->select('keys')
        ->whereNotNull('keys')
        ->where('name', $container)
        ->value('keys');
}

$keys = Containers::keys($container);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fit the bill:

```
public function scopeKeys($query, $container)
{
    $query = $query->select('keys')
        ->whereNotNull('keys')
        ->where('name', $container)
        ->first();

    if (is_null($keys)) {
        return json_encode((object) null);
    }
    return $query->keys;
}
```

...and allows me to keep the controller clean:

```
public function index($container)
{
    $rsp = Containers::keys($container);

    return response($rsp)
        ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'text/json']);
}
```

Open to input - thanks all.